# PHP magic methods behave differently when dynamically building property names

Tags: php, getter-setter, magic-methods

I have two examples of a simple class using the `__set()` and `__get()` magic methods.  One throws a fatal error and the other does not when attempting to access a protected property with the `unset()` function.

In Example 1, I'm naming my protected property *starting* with an underscore and allowing access via the friendly name and prepending the underscore in my `__set()` and `__get()` methods.  (Effectively exposing the property without an underscore).

In Example 2, I'm **not** starting the name with an underscore and allowing access via the name directly in the `__set()` and `__get()` methods.

**Questions**

1) Why does Example 1 **not** throw a fatal error while Example 2 **does** throw a fatal error?  I would expect either both to throw the error or neither to throw the error.

2) Also, why does Example 1 **not** actually unset the property?  I would expect the property to not contain a value after the `unset()` function is called.

**Example 1**

```
class Example {

    protected $_my_property;

    function __get($name) {
        echo '<h4>__get() was triggered!</h4>';
        $name = '_' . $name;
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            return $this->$name;
        }
        else {
            trigger_error("Undefined property in __get(): $name");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    function __set($name, $value) {
        echo '<h4>__set() was triggered!</h4>';
        $name = '_' . $name;
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            $this->$name = $value;
            return;
        }
        else {
            trigger_error("Undefined property in __set(): {$name}");
        }
    }

}

$myExample = new Example();
$myExample->my_property = 'my_property now has a value';
echo $myExample->my_property;
unset($myExample->my_property);
echo "Did I unset my property?: {$myExample->my_property}";
```

**Example 2**

```
class Example {

    protected $my_property;

    function __get($name) {
        echo '<h4>__get() was triggered!</h4>';
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            return $this->$name;
        }
        else {
            trigger_error("Undefined property in __get(): $name");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    function __set($name, $value) {
        echo '<h4>__set() was triggered!</h4>';
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            $this->$name = $value;
            return;
        }
        else {
            trigger_error("Undefined property in __set(): {$name}");
        }
    }

}

$myExample = new Example();
$myExample->my_property = 'my_property now has a value';
echo $myExample->my_property;
unset($myExample->my_property);
echo "Did I unset my property?: {$myExample->my_property}";
```

As a side note, this is just a simplistic example that demonstrates the behavior I'm seeing in my real world project.  Thanks!

Comment: I think your question would be clearer if you included the property declarations.  This behavior could easily by caused by failing to initialize one of the properties.

Comment: @SamDufel Thanks, but I don't think I understand what you mean. In my code samples I have declared the protected properties inside the class as `protected $_my_property;` for example, and have initialized it outside the class as `$myExample->my_property = 'my_property now has a value';` for example.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I'm blind in the morning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you have not defined an `__unset()` magic method.

This means that when you call `unset($myExample->my_property)`, it is trying to directly unset a public property with the specified name.

In example 1, the real protected property has an underscore in it's name. Therefore, when you try to unset the property, PHP looks at the object, sees that there is nothing with the specified name, and effectively ignores it.

This is the same behaviour that `unset()` would exhibit if you tried to unset a non-existent variable or array element.

However in example 2, the protected property has the same name as you have given in the `unset()` call.

In this example, PHP looks at the object and sees that the property does exist but that it it is non-accessible. It therefore throws an error complaining that it can't unset the property.

You can resolve this issue by including an `__unset()` method alongside your `__get()` and `__set()` methods. If you're planning to use magic methods, you should ideally define all three.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent explanation, I appreciate it!  Yes, I'll add an `__unset()` magic method and follow the same pattern.